# Xamarin Master Detail handle generics

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin, xamarin.forms, generic-list

I have read the [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/) on the xamarin web site.

However I would like to create a Master which is able to handle generics. For this reason my implementation of MasterPageItem is a little bit different

```
public interface IMasterPageItem<TPage, TViewModel>
    where TPage : Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage
    where TViewModel : ViewModel.BaseViewModel
{
        TPage Page { get; }

        TViewModel ViewModel { get; }
}


public class MasterPageItem<TPage, TViewModel> : IMasterPageItem<TPage, TViewModel>
    where TPage : Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage
    where TViewModel : ViewModel.BaseViewModel
{
    public TPage Page { get; set; }

    public TViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

However I am having problems to build the List of page items

```
var masterPageItems = new List<IMasterPageItem<?,?>>();
masterPageItems.Add( new MasterPageItem<HomePage, HomePageViewModel>() );
```

as well as other problems to handle the click event on the listview

```
public void ListView_ItemSelected( object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e ) {
    var item = e.Item as IMasterPageItem<?,?>;
    [...]
}
```

Is there any way I can use MasterDetail by using generics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your interface a bit, by making both `TPage` and `TViewModel` covariant (out modifier):

```
public interface IMasterPageItem<out TPage, out TViewModel>
    where TPage : Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage
    where TViewModel : BaseViewModel {

    TPage Page { get; }
    TViewModel ViewModel { get; }
}
```

Then you are able to do this:

```
var masterPageItems = new List<IMasterPageItem<Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage, BaseViewModel>>();
masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem<HomePage, HomePageViewModel>());
```

And this:

```
var item = e.Item as IMasterPageItem<Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage, BaseViewModel>;
```